# Is the trackpad surface different on MacBook Air than the Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

Is the trackpad surface on a MacBook Air different than on a Pro? I found that the trackpad on my friend's 2012 MacBook Pro is much smoother than that of my 2013 MacBook Air. Is that normal or my has my trackpad gone rough by use?

Comment: I currently own a new Macbook Pro 2015, and a macbook Air 2015 for a week, both are brand new. The Trackpad of the Macbook Pro is far softer and responsive, the Macbook Air seems cheap in comparison and as if you are touch a rock in comparison.

Comment: that may be the new force touch trackpad you are experiencing, in march and may last year apple updated the macbook pro's to include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trackpad surface is the same on both the MacBook Air and MacBook Pro. It's the iconic glass on metal design (patent [D674382](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/D674382.html)). The trackpad design and hardware has been the same since it's introduction in 2008 with the new MacBooks.
[image]