# macbook pro retina keyboard and trackpad key press

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro, trackpad

I had 3 different macbooks, macbook 13, macbook 13 retina and now I have macbook 15 retina. When I bought macbook 13 retina I've noticed that keyboard and touchpad differs a little from what I had earlier: keys and touchpad pressings became quieter and shorter, but on retina 15 I have the same keyboard and touchpad as on the first one. Is this normal? I've bought it from resellers and wonder if there any trick from their side. Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the trackpad surface different on MacBook Air than the Pro?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150730/is-the-trackpad-surface-different-on-macbook-air-than-the-pro)

Comment: @jash-jacob, no, it's not

Comment: They're all the same trackpads.

Comment: No, they are not. They look the same, but feels different. Older models click deeper, it's another sound and another feeling when you use it.The same with the keyboard. If have nothing more to say, please, just leave the question open and let other people answer it